# install scrapy mac 2.7

Tags: python, macos, curl, scrapy

I try install scrapy in my mac os x 1.8.5 and very difficult.

I try to install de "easy tools" (are not easy ;)) with instruction of page:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
```

and the command:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
```

but always error:

```
iMac-de-ERIKA:~ root$ curl bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
  % Total    % Received %   Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11434  100 11434    0     0  48685      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 61473
Downloading pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-18.0.1.zip
Extracting in /tmp/tmpMz4MuT
Now working in /tmp/tmpMz4MuT/asetuptools-18.0.1a
Installing Setuptools
running install
Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-725.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
```

I have tried delete the directories with root user but allways:

```
iMac-de-ERIKA:~ root$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
rm: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/README: Permission denied
rm: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages: Permission denied
```

How apply the "--install-dir" parameter to this instruction?
Some solution for install scrapy in my mac?

Can you help me?

Thanks so much!!!

Xavier.

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that this will install some other packages on the system apart from scrapy, I would recommend installing homebrew, then pip and then scrapy from it.
The commands in order are

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew install python
brew install pip
pip install scrapy
```

You can find more information about the packages on http://brew.sh/, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip respectively.
Basically brew is a package manager for mac os x, and pip is a package manager for python. Installing python from brew installs pip with it, but just in case, you can install it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Like the [idea of Akshat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307229/3941341) however in my case I used `sudo` to install Python packages with `pip` -- including Scrapy. If you are the admin of your Mac try executing the above commands with `sudo` to get write access as it is stated in the error log.